# problems with creating an osgi plugin

Tags: xpages

I am currently using the XSP starter kit from openntf. I didnt change the template at all i just wanted to try it first with the starter kit before i am going to change it.

I am following the documentation on notesin9 and everything works fine until i want to build the update site.

Whenever i try to build it i got the error message:

Error

Reason:
Problem during export

Details:

BUILD FAILED
java.lang.NullPointerException

As this message is not very useful has anybody experienced the same issue?

Comment: Check the log, what does it tell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple of days of testing i found out: The error doesnt go to the log. It happens from time to time if  you have the same plugin installed on the client where you also build a newer version of the same plugin. The way to fix that is to manually uninstall the plugin from your client, restart, and then build it again. I can reproduce it after a couple of rebuilds